# What will be OAuth 2.0 Authorized Redirect URLs in LinkedIn For Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, linkedin-api, phonegap-build

I'am developing Phonegap app for android and ios. For SignIn use LinkedIn. But stuck what will be authorized redirect url i specify in LinkedIn at the time of the app creation. My html pages are reside in app locally.

Thanks in advance.